# Cookies working in Flex but not in Air

Tags: apache-flex, air

I've got a flex app which I'm porting to air, the two apps are identical except for the root tag being WindowedApplication rather than Application.

The problem is that cookie/session based logins are working for the flex app in the browser but not for the air app. Reading the docs says that cookies are available for air and the URLRequest manageCookies is true by default.

So does anyone have any idea which this is not working in Air?

**********************UPDATE********************************

I've investigated further and it turns out cookies are working in Air and are used for all subsequent requests after the login, but the cookie does not survive a shutdown of the application and the user is required to login again when they restart.

So Question 2, is this expected behaviour? If so I will look into storing the cookie info in EncrptedLocalStore or something.

**********************UPDATE********************************

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Cookies are a browser invention.  In AIR, there is no browser, and  would therefore assume no cookies.  You might be able to pull the cookie values out of your return request, store them locally somehow, and add them as headers onto every remote calls every time.  Or look for alternatives to server side sessions.

Comment: Air is built on top of Webkit. That's also not what's suggested here - http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/08/single-sign-on-and-http-cookies-in-air-applications.html

Comment: Or here - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html#manageCookies

Comment: This question has been unanswered for six months, it's also been unanswered on the Adobe forum, for six months - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/764275?tstart=0 SO I've put a 200 point bounty down for whoever can show me how to make a session persist after the shutdown and restart of an air app.

Comment: Im just throwing darts in complete blackness here, but the storing part can be done using sqlite.Not sure, how would you retrieve them, when they are needed the next time.

Comment: Your session based login, how does it work? Do you just need to keep the session id?  Can you explain more what exactly you were doing with the browser cookies?

Comment: I would expect it to be expected behavior that cookies in an AIR app are cleared with each application restart.  I bet you could store them as a Shared Object somehow.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com : Yup!!! The reason is browser instance and Application instance are quite different. You need to store them in a localstore...

Answer (score 3):

> "AIR picks up cookie settings from the
>   operating system, and not the browser.
>   It just happens though that some
>   browsers also use the operating system
>   settings / cookies."

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLRequest.html#manageCookies

http://prsync.com/adobe/more-on-sharing-http-cookies-with-air-applications-107386/

> I've investigated further and it turns
>   out cookies are working in Air and are
>   used for all subsequent requests after
>   the login, but the cookie does not
>   survive a shutdown of the application
>   and the user is required to login
>   again when they restart.
>
> So Question 2, is this expected
>   behaviour? If so I will look into
>   storing the cookie info in
>   EncrptedLocalStore or something.

Yes go ahead with EncrptedLocalStore.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

**Update**

http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/08/single-sign-on-and-http-cookies-in-air-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSacd9bdd0c5c09f4a-690d4877120e8b878b0-7fed.html) to store ot retrieve cookies. Theese cookies are from system default browser.

Comment: I'm not loading HTML from Rails, I'm loading a RubyAMF service which is called over HTTP. There is an Air only property called manageCookies with defaults to true which leads me to believe that there is cookie support in Air - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#manageCookies

Comment: Exactly because you need to work with cookies you _must_ use additional control that implements cookie mechanism. You can make it invisible, use it in parallel, catch the complete event for example and then do base things.